# Simplifying a multi-purpose bookkeeping set-up

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to create a workbook which features an annual financial record as well as a monthly record and a daily record - - i.e., each day someone would record a line by line record of sales and purchases and taxes paid and collected, which would show up in the monthly recap and the annual recap sheets as each and every change is recorded.

To date I've created one workbook that contains the annual recap sheet plus a different sheet for each month and I've created twelve individual workbooks (one for each month of the year), with each workbook containing one sheet for each day of the month).

In order to do what I'd like, I've created a cell for accumulated daily totals.  It appears that the next step would be to copy the daily totals onto a recap sheet (within each "Monthly" workbook), with a different line for each day of the month and have their accumulated totals linked in the monthly sheet within the other workbook - - which seems like a lot of work, thus my question:
- - is there an easier method to set this up and achieve the desired results??

ALSO
I've created a "master" of each of these workbooks so that copies can be made for each year (eg: I've named one workbook Master for February Daily Records - and then re-saved it using the name February Daily records 2014 and would like to re-save it again each year as February Daily Records 2015, etc...  It appears that all the work I'm putting in to creating the results I'm looking for will need to be repeated each time I change the name of the workbook, thus my second question
- - is there a way to create master workbooks and then rename them without loosing all the formulas, etc., that were set up in the master workbooks??

Any/all suggestions and help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It's of interest that you say you wouldn't use my approach - - would you mind sharing with me how you would do this??    In regards to archiving - - this is what I do with a far less complicated file, however, my tests with the file I'm currently putting together (as a favour to a man who is starting up a small business and has no bookkeeping skills), it appears that when I save the file in a new name, the links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep everything (except lookup tables and the like) in the one sheet and for archiving, once a year save the complete file, rename a copy and delete its data (not formulae, not formatting).

Describing in details is way beyond the scope of SO but the image below might give a little indication of what is possible, in all the possibilities are virtually infinite.

[image: SO21618710 example]

Note that for the sake of the image I have put all the PT on the same sheet (each could and perhaps even should be on its own sheet) - but they are all driven by a single pivot cache.

Comment: I appreciate your time in providing me with some new food for thought.  Your image shows a great deal of information being displayed all on one sheet - - now I'll see if I can duplicate what you've done  :o).   Thanks again - much appreciated.